# iPhone: Huge memory spike when creating NSString in loop

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, automatic-ref-counting

I'm having a memory issue that leads to a crash. I am looping through an array of dictionaries and then inside that I loop through a keys array that I created. I use each key in that keys array to get the value of that key in the dictionary. I then create a string by appending the values. This string will contain a large amount of data.

I am also using ARC so I can't manually release.

The memory spike happens on the stringByAppendingFormat line.

```
    NSString *theString = [[NSString alloc] init];
for (NSMutableDictionary *aDict in collectionArray)
{
    for (NSString *key in itemKeys)
    {
        NSString *valueString = [aDict valueForKey:key];

        // Memory spikes here
        theString = [theString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@,", valueString];
    }
}
```

Comment: How many entries are in the aDict dictionary and itemKeys array?

Comment: you are leaking `theString`. over and over again.

Comment: Maybe a NSMutableString (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/) would be more appropriate for this. You can use appendString with it. You could also precalculate the required buffer capacity in advance

Comment: What results are you expecting? theString is going to grow exponentially. How big is collectionArray?

Comment: @DanielA.White this isn't leaking, it is using ARC.

Comment: @DanielA.White I don't think it would leak, since it's an autoreleased object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `NSString`, you should use an `NSMutableString`. Try this:

```
NSMutableString *theString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (NSMutableDictionary *aDict in collectionArray)
{
    for (NSString *key in itemKeys)
    {
        NSString *valueString = [aDict valueForKey:key];

        // Memory spikes here
        [theString appendFormat:@"%@,", valueString];
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
This will probably solve your problems if your dictionary and the lengths of the `itemKeys` are not particularly large. However, if they are large you'll need to use an autoreleasepool in your loop like they do here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7804798/211292 Also, consider Tommy's change if all you are doing is separating the values by commas.

Answer (score 4):

Putting aside the issues answered elsewhere — that you constantly create a new string that includes the old plus some extra, leaving the old on the autorelease pool which won't be drained at least until you exit the method — the following:

```
NSArray *values = [aDict objectsForKeys:itemKeys notFoundMarker:@""];
theString = [values componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

Would appear to do what you want (well, if you add an extra comma on the end) without any explicit sort of inner loop.